# Simple calculation returning NullPointer exception... why?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

(I'm new to Java so please forgive my ignorance).

I have a very simple class:

```
public class Bill {
    private String Total;
    private int Tip;
    private int People;
    Bill() {
        Total = "0";
        Tip=0;
        People=0;
    }
    Bill (String total, int people, int tip) {
        Total = total;
        Tip = tip;
        People = people;
    }

    //the problem is here somewhere.
    private Double Split = (Double.parseDouble(Total) * ((double)Tip / 100)) / (double)People;

    public String getTotal() {
        return Total;
    }

    public double getSplit() {
        return Split;
    }

    public double getTip() {
        return Tip;
    }

}
```

When I call the 'getSplit()' method, the runtime crashes with a NullPointer exception:

```
09-03 19:37:02.609: E/AndroidRuntime(11325): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 19:37:02.609: E/AndroidRuntime(11325):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:244)
09-03 19:37:02.609: E/AndroidRuntime(11325):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
09-03 19:37:02.609: E/AndroidRuntime(11325):    at williamgill.de.helloworld.Bill.<init>(Bill.java:21)
09-03 19:37:02.609: E/AndroidRuntime(11325):    at williamgill.de.helloworld.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:38)
```

I seem to be doing something obviously wrong with the casting of types - but I can't for the life of me think what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time this line executes

```
private Double Split = (Double.parseDouble(Total) * ((double)Tip / 100)) / (double)People;
```

The fields `Total` and others have not been initialized by the constructor and have a default value of `null`. `parseDouble()` must throw a `NullPointerException` if its argument is `null` (I cannot verify this, it might also come from dereferencing).

Declare that field

```
private Double Split;
```

and do the assignment in the constructor

```
Bill (String total, int people, int tip) {
    Total = total;
    Tip = tip;
    People = people;
    Split = (Double.parseDouble(Total) * ((double)Tip / 100)) / (double)People;
}
```

Advice: Java non-constant instance variables should start with a lowercase alphabetical character.

Comment: Another advice: constructors should be `public`.

Comment: And variables, like your methods, should begin with a lower case letter according to the Java convention.

Comment: thank you - that solves my problem. Makes total sense once you say it like that... :) Thanks again!

Comment: @WillGill You are welcome. Please heed the advice given in the comments and follow Java conventions.

Comment: Speaking of capital letters - is there a difference between Double and double?

Comment: @WillGill One is a reference type, the other is a primitive type. Those are keywords that you can look up :).

Comment: `Double` is an object. `double` is a primitive.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Fair enough. You can't change the value of a variable passed to a method but you can change the value of its properties. The primitives have no mutable properties (as do some objects, like `Double`) so it is of no concern in those cases. I've changed my comment though to avoid confusion that isn't really related to this question.